# create socket after io_service run

Tags: c++, sockets, boost-asio

In all examples of using boost, usually people do the following

```
boost::asio::io_service io_service;
tcp::socket s1(io_service);
tcp::socket s2(io_service);
io_service.run();
```

But i am writing class that already has running in thread io_service and it has to create sockets with this io_service. And there is my question. How to make it thread safety?

```
class MySocket
{
private:

    boost::asio::io_service* ioService;
    tcp::socket* socket;
public:
     MySocket(boost::asio::io_service* nioService,
              tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator):
    ioService(nioService)
    {
        socket = new tcp::socket(*ioService);
    }
     ~MySocket();
};

SocketHandler handler;
handler.run(); //run io_service in thread
MySocket* s1 = handler.createSocket("localhost", "80");
//do something
MySocket* s2 = handler.createSocket("localhost", "81");
//dododo
handler.destroySocket(s1);
handler.destroySocket(s2);
```

Comment: Can you post your code for more clarity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create new sockets at any time with boost::asio.

`io_service::run()` blocks until working queue is empty. If it there is no work in the queue - the function returns immediately. That's why people usually add work to it (create timers, bind sockets, etc) prior to `io_service::run()`.

BTW: I don't recommend doing this way:

```
MySocket* s1 = handler.createSocket("localhost", "80");
...
handler.destroySocket(s1);
```

use RAII-objects (smart pointers) instead.